# Why "%E2%80%8E" are added after the link?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4, redirect, razor

I have a website you can redirect to another website. But some links redirected with %E2%80%8E. But most sites redirected on the right way.

By debugging is see the following:
item.Link gives "www.somesite.com/" and the link redirected "www.somesite.com/%E2%80%8E"

item.Link gives "www.mostsites.com/" and the link redirected "www.mostsites.com/"

What can be the problem? It's a MVC4 website with Razor technology.

```
<span class="label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Organization)</span>
@{
  if (item.Link == null || item.Link == "")
  {
    <span>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Organization)</span>
  }
  else
  {
    <span><a href="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Link)" target="_blank">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Organization)</a></span>
  }
}
```

I see as a solution like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*) index.php?model=$1&view=$2¶meters=$3 [L,NS]
```

But why do I have to place in my MVC application???

Comment: This has nothing to do with MVC, those are non-printable characters which are copy-pasted from for example MS Word. See duplicate. If your question is _"How can I prevent this?"_, try sanitizing your input before saving it in the database, for example using string.Replace().

Comment: The data comes from a xml-file. You can see it as the "database".

Comment: Yeah well then clean it up before returning it from your controller.

Comment: Okay I rewrite those 2 Link-elements. And now it works fine. So the problem has solved. Thanks. But where should I have to write that code. Do that makes my code better?

Comment: And I didn't use Word but VS2010.